# Can you have a concentration result for $1/\sqrt{n}$ deviation?

Tags: probability, random-variables, central-limit-theorem, concentration-of-measure

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ be nonnegative bounded random variables either independent or negatively associated (stronger condition than negatively correlated). Let $\mathbb{E}\left [\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right ] = \mu$.

Then by Chebyshev, we have approximately,
$$\mathbb{P}\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mu > \Delta \right) \leq \frac{1}{n \Delta^2},$$
or by Chernoff-Hoeffding, we get approximately

$$\mathbb{P}\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mu > \Delta \right) \leq \exp \left( - n \Delta^2 \right).$$

There are other concentration inequalities too but in each case to get concentration (i.e., get decaying probability), we need to choose $\Delta = \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2} - \epsilon}}.$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.

That $\epsilon > 0$ is really messing up a result I am trying to prove. Are there any extra regularity conditions I can impose or perhaps use other concentration inequalities which could help me get concentration for deviations equal to $1/\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: A good thing to do: check what happens for a sum of Gaussians, or a Binomial -- is that behaviour good enough for you? It's unlikely you'll get better.

Comment: Deviations of order $1/\sqrt{n}$ are handled by central limit theorems. So if you can show that your sum over the $X_i$s satisfies a central limit theorem you can express such concentration equalities by the probability of a normal distribution for large $n$.